# C# code generation without spaces with NRefactory

Tags: c#, code-generation, nrefactory

Is it possible to set up formatting options for C# code generation without spaces and line breaks?

I mean the transformation of the following code:

```cs
using System;
class Test
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

to this code:

```cs
using System;class Test{public void Main(string[] args){Console.WriteLine("Hello, World");}}
```

I am trying to do it with empty options, but it is does not work.

```cs
SyntaxTree syntaxTree;
CSharpFormattingOptions emptyOptions = FormattingOptionsFactory.CreateEmpty();
sting CSharpCode = syntaxTree.GetText(emptyOptions);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why on earth would you want to do this?

Comment: @Kjartan, for automatic conversation of usual C# code to it's own minified version, which can be used in such freaky programs as an easy quine or complex [selfprinting game of life](http://igoro.com/archive/self-printing-game-of-life-in-c/). Space and line breaks removing is one of several automatic minification steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created project for C# code minification based on NRefactory: [CSharpMinifier](https://github.com/KvanTTT/CSharpMinifier)

Code for whitespace removing located in this file: [Minifier.cs](https://github.com/KvanTTT/CSharpMinifier/blob/master/CSharpMinifier/Minifier.cs)